What would be the function y(r) of the y-coordinate of the center of a circle with radius r dropped on a cosine function at x=π?
Imagine dropping a circle with radius $r$ on a cosine wave at $x=\pi$, so it is tangent (and perpendicular) at two points. What would would be the y-coordinate of the center of the circle? One way to approach this problem would be to describe the cosine wave as a parametric equation, and then by taking the derivative you get the direction vector. The vector from the two points where the two curves touch to the center of the circle is perpendicular to the direction vector, so by resizing the vector to be of size $r$ you can get the two points you want. And from there you can get the y-coordinate with some geometry. But with this method and other methods I encountered difficult equations I couldn't solve algebraically like:
$$y(r)+\cos(a)=\sqrt{r^2-a^2}$$
where $a$ is the solution to:
$$\frac{r\sin(\pi-a)}{\sqrt{\sin^2(\pi-a)+1}}+\pi - a = \frac{r\sin(\pi+a)}{\sqrt{\sin^2(\pi+a)+1}}+\pi + a$$
By calculating the value numerically I found $y(2)=1.258329963\ldots$
Also I think $$\lim_{r\to\infty} y(r)-r=1$$ because it will go closer and closer to touching $(0, 1)$ and $(2\pi, 1)$, and $y(r)=r-1$ for all $r\leq 1$.
Is there a way to solve this problem algebraically using this method or another method? And what does the graph of the $y(r)$ function look like?

The equation "$\lim_{r\to\infty} y(r)=r+1$" is nonsensical, as the left side does not depend on $r$ while the right side does. (That $r$ on the left side is a dummy variable. The limit does not depend on it, but rather only on the function and the target $r$ is approaching - in this case, $\infty$.)  What you apparently mean is $\lim_{r\to\infty} y(r)-r = 1$.

@PaulSinclair Oh oops I'll edit that, I've just done highschool calculus so I'm not yet very familiar with all the rules of limits

In this case, it is the much broader concept of variable scope that you need to be aware of: where in a discussion is a variable first defined, and where does that definition end? For dummy variables, the scope is just a single expression. They are necessary to make the notation work, but have no meaning outside of it. Limits are just one example. Variables introduced by the phrases "for all ..." or "there exists" also commonly introduce variables that have meaning only for a short range of statements, though there is often no clear indication where that range ends. Only experience tells.

You are correct that the limit is $1$. There are many, many algebraic equations like this that cannot be solved symbolically. However, there are common techniques allowing you to fairly easily calculate solutions to any desired accuracy. Newton's method is the most famous example. (There is no such thing as calculating solutions to exact accuracy, unless they are rational. Even for equations that you can "solve", the "solution" will consist of operations that cannot be exactly calculated. We do not even know the exact value of $\sqrt 2$.)

@PaulSinclair Well that's more a philosophical discussion of what it means to know a value. If you define it as being able to write a finite decimal expansion of the number in an certain base you are right we don't know the value of $\sqrt{2}$. But being able to write it algebraically still has upsides. For one you can find derivatives, limits, etc. more easily. Also even if the equation I used doesn't have an algebraic solution, maybe another method does have one. Also sometimes new functions get introduced to solve equations that were previously unsolvable, like the Lambert W function.

No it is not a philosophical discussion, but a practical one. Yes, you can write the solution in terms of some function. Indeed, you can use the very equation that is being solved to define such a function. But how does that help? If I say that the solution is $\mathcal F\left(\frac{23}{14}\right)$, where $\cal F$ is some esoteric function, I haven't really stated anything useful about the solution. I still have to perform some approximation procedure just to compare my result to other numbers, or to produce any useful information about it. All I done is delay the calculation, not avoid it.

@PaulSinclair As I said, when you can define the solution as some function you can find more information about that function, like it's derivative, primitive and limits. For practical stuff, you can find a plot of the function, literature on the function, approximations, etc etc. If there was no point in making such functions why would we have a square root sign?

You can get all that information from the original function whose root you are solving for. There is no need to write the solution in terms of some other function to find it. To plot the solution function, you need to do that evaluation which can usually be obtained more easily by Newton's method on the original function than by introducing a new function to provide the root and then laboriously developing its properties. This is why most advanced analysis is given to showing solutions exist and the circumstances making them unique, not to producing equations for them.
